# How To detect changes in Bootstrap Multiselect

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

Is it possible to detect whether there have been any changes in a Bootstrap Muiltiselcts options upon closing the dropdown. I want to use the `onDropdownHidden` event documented here on the authors docs page: [onDropDownHidden Event](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-onDropdownShown) to allow me to see if the user has de-selected or selected anything since the drop down was opened. Upon opening the multi-select will have some pre-selected options. I need to know (especially) whether they have toggled an option (thus no change to initial selections) so i can decide whether to call a function to initiate saving the new changes. I want to avoid just calling this function after an `onChange` of an option if the resultant state is the same. Its similar to isDirty used to check if any control on a form has been edited - is there some similar technique for Multi-select??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So does the multiselect have a default value that is set?  Are these selects only going to be used when updating/adding something to a database?

I can't really tell if you want to use javascript or PHP, but if you're using PHP, would it make sense to either check `if isset($multiselectfield){}` ?

Or more simply simply if it has a default value, check `if ($multiselectfield != defaultvalue) {}`.  If it isn't the default value then do that, otherwise the default value must have been left alone.

Just my thoughts, but the questions ins't exactly worded to be able to give you an adequate answer.  I'm just taking a stab at it anyway.

Comment: Upon initialisation the multiselects will have some options checked as read from the database. Im updating via jquery ajax `$post()` with the multiselct data serialized. Then in PHP ill update the table. Im thinking along the lines of: Read the initial state of each option, store all states and then `onDropdownHidden` comparing the states if anything has changed -show a (pre-hidden) 'Save Changes' button. Just wondered if this is necessary if theres a better inbuilt method, technique or something unknown to me.

Comment: I that's definitely a way for you to do it.  I believe, however the `onDropdownHidden` is more of a UI feature than anything.  You'll still want to get their values and see if they are set, so I'm not sure you need to check the state of `onDrodownHidden`, but you should need to check the values for each select themselves.  You could limit the amount you have the server do by adding some conditional statements, checking whether they are set before actually getting the value from POST.  That's just what I'm envisioning, but It sounds like you're on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

#### For JS & JQuery User's

This is how I resolved this problem.

```js
/*
 * This variable will be used to track whether:
 * The selected values for the dropdown before opening it is same while closing or not.
 * Reason behind tracking?
 * If user just opened and closed the dropdown without selecting or deselecting the options,
 * the handler assigned to onDropdownHide event will be fired that is not expected.
 */
let monthValueBeforeDropdownShown;

// This function simply capture the selected options
// and put it in the variable
function captureValuesBeforeDropdownShown() {
    monthValueBeforeDropdownShown = $("#drop-down-id").val();
}

$("#drop-down-id").multiselect({
    onDropdownShow: captureValuesBeforeDropdownShown,
    onDropdownHide: exitMonthChangeHandler
});

function exitMonthChangeHandler() {
    // If no values are present (nothing selected) we'll terminate
    if(!$("#drop-down-id").val().length) return;

    // Comparing the dropdown values before opening and after closing.
    // If there is no change we'll terminate
    if (monthValueBeforeDropdownShown.toString() === $("#drop-down-id").val().toString()) return;

    // HERE YOU CAN WRITE YOUR AJAX OR WHATEVER LOGIC YOU WANT
}
```

PS: There is still some margin to optimize this code by utilizing the Modern JS High Order Functions.